# why does it returns '-1' instead of the index of the index jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm running a 'for' loop to check if the elements in the `winOptions` array are in the `oneNums` array. However, every time I use `indexOf` property it sends back `-1` even if the number is in the `oneNums` array. Is it possible it returns that because `['1','2']` is different that `[1,2]`? How can I fix this.

I have this variables:

```
 var oneNums = [];
 var winOptions = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]];
 var a;
```

And this jQuery function:

```
$('.btn-xo').click(function(){
  if (turn === 'one'){
    $(this).text(pickOne);
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    oneNums.push($(this).val());
    oneNums.sort(function(a, b){
      return a - b;
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < winOptions.length; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < winOptions[i].length; j++){
        a = oneNums.indexOf(winOptions[i][j]);
        if (a === -1){
          p1 = [];
          break;
        } else {
          p1.push(oneNums[a]);
          console.log('aca');
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(a);
    turn = 'two';
    count += 1;        
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet for this as your code has some missing vars

Comment: @Harsheet give me a sec. I'll do it.

Comment: `oneNums.push(parseInt($(this).val(), 10));` can check parsing it?

Comment: Print oneNums array and check,whether it is having preferred values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexOf` string with number will fail. So, **change `number` to `string`**

First convert number to String, using `.toString()`

```
for(var i = 0; i < winOptions.length; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < winOptions[i].length; j++){
        a = oneNums.indexOf((winOptions[i][j]).toString());
        if (a === -1){
          p1 = [];
          break;
        } else {
          p1.push(oneNums[a]);
          console.log('aca');
        }
      }
    }
```

Check these two examples,

**`['1','2'].indexOf(1); o/p  ===> -1`**

**`['1','2'].indexOf((1).toString()); o/p  ===> 0`**

Comment: Exactly what I was asking for. So it is different the `1` and the `'1'`. Thanks!

Comment: @DiegoRios, yes your suspicion is correct, that's the culprit. :)